# How can I update component in React after adding a new item into the database, using react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I want to update the component after adding a new comment which gets stored into the backend and updates the previously displayed component with the new one which has a new comment.

**Here is the Page.js** which loads a single post/article and its comments:

```js
import React ,{useState, useContext, useEffect}from 'react';
import {useHistory,Redirect, useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'


import '../CSS/Page.css'

import CreateComment from './CreateComment';



const  Page=()=>{



const [show,setShow]=useState({
    commentBox:false
})

 const [post,setPost] = useState(
     {id:'', username:'', title:'',body:'',date:'',comments:[{}]
    }) 
let {postTitle}=useParams()




useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:2000/apiEndpoint/singlePost/${postTitle}`,{withCredentials:true},{
        headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }

    }).then((res)=>{
        console.log(res.data)
        const postS=res.data
        setPost({...post,id:postS._id,  username:postS.username, title:postS.title, body:postS.body,comments: postS.comments})
        
        return;
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log([err])
    })
  },[]);

  const handleCommentButton=(e)=>{
    
    setShow({ ...show, commentBox:!show.commentBox });
    
    
    
}

    return (
        
        <div className='postContainer'>
            <div className='singlePostcontainer'>
                <div className='singlePost' >
                    <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                    <hr/>
                    <p>{post.body} </p>
                    {post.id}
                    <hr/>
                    <h5>Comments:<button className='btnCom' onClick={handleCommentButton}>{show.commentBox?'Close':'Add Comment'}</button></h5>
                    {show.commentBox?(<CreateComment post={post} />):''}
                    {post.comments.map(comment=>{
                        
                        const commentID=comment._id
                        return(
                            <div className='comment' key={commentID}>

                                <h3>{comment.body}</h3>
                                <h6>By: {comment.creater}</h6>
                        
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        
            
        </div>
        )
}


export default Page
```

**Here is the CreateComment.js** component which has a form and post request to the database:

```js
import React, { Component,useState, useEffect, lazy } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
const axios = require('axios').default;



const CreateComment=(props)=>{
    var commentStr={
        body:''
        
    }
    const [comment, setComment] = useState(commentStr);
    
    
         
    
    
         const handleSubmitA=(e)=>{
             e.preventDefault()
             console.log('This is the id:',props.post.id)
             axios.post(`http://localhost:2000/apiEndpoint/CREATE/comment/${props.post.id}`,{
                 body:comment.body
             },
             {withCredentials:true},{
                headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              }}).then(res=>{
                  console.log(res);
                  
                })
         }
     
    
    
        const handleChangeA=(e)=>{
            const {name,value}=e.target
            setComment({ ...comment, [name]: value });
            
        }
    
   
   
        return(
            <div className='commentContainer'>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmitA}>
                <label>Enter Comment</label>
                <textarea name="body" onChange={handleChangeA}></textarea>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
            
                
            
            </div>
        )

    

}


export default CreateComment
```

I'm able to add component successfully and it is also posting the comment to the backend database also. But it only shows on the page if I press reload.

I removed the empty array from inside of useEffect hook. It gives me an infinite loop but does the work correctly. However as that is not a good practice and it takes up local storage resources, how can I perform the same task but without the infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually not updating the post after posting a comment.

### Simple

An easy solution would be to have `<CreateComment />` accept a callback that can signal  the parent that a new comment is available. The parent could then decide what to do with that information. You could trigger a refetch of the post to get all other comments and state updates that might have been summited while the user was working on their comment.

```
const CreateComment = (props) => {
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('This is the id:', props.post.id)
    axios.post(`http://localhost:2000/apiEndpoint/CREATE/comment/${props.post.id}`, {
      body: comment.body
    }, {
      withCredentials: true
    }, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(res => {
      props.onCommentCreated();
    });
  };
};
```

If your api returns a comment, you could instead use `props.onCommentCreated(res.data)` to pass the comment up to the parent. You would then not need to refetch since the parent would just push it into their comments state slice.

### Fancy

If you  want to get really fancy, you might consider completely removing the logic of handling posts/comments from the components and stick it all into a hook. This makes your logic reusable. Its also easier to reason about since the `usePost` hook has a very well defined api and all of the state wrangling is happening behind the scene. I didnt test this at all so you will have to adjust this if you go this route.

```
const EMPTY_POST = {
  id: '',
  username: '',
  title: '',
  body: '',
  date: '',
  comments: [{}]
}

const getPost = (title) => {
  return axios.get(`http://localhost:2000/apiEndpoint/singlePost/${title}`, {
    withCredentials: true
  }, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then((res) => res.data);
};

const postComment = (id, content) => {
  return axios.post(`http://localhost:2000/apiEndpoint/CREATE/comment/${id}`, {
    body: content
  }, {
    withCredentials: true
  }, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
}

const usePost = () => {
  const [post, setPost] = useState(EMPTY_POST);
  const {
    title
  } = useParams();

  const findPost = (title) => {
    getPost(title)
      .then((res) => {
        const postS = res.data;

        setPost({
          ...post,
          id: postS._id,
          username: postS.username,
          title: postS.title,
          body: postS.body,
          comments: postS.comments
        })
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(":(", e);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    findPost(title)
  }, []);

  const createComment = (id, comment) => {
    postComment(id, comment)
      .then(() => findPosts(title)); // refetch?
      
    postComment(id, comment)
        .then((result) => {
          setPost({ ...post, comments: [...post.comments, result]}));
        }); // just include it in.
  }

  return {
    post,
    createComment
  };
}
```

So now that your post logic is in a single hook, you could just use that as in your components. Here is an abbreviated version that shows a possible implementation.

```
const Page = () => {
  const { post, createComment } = usePost();

  return (
    ...
    {show.commentBox && <CreateComment post={post} onSubmit={createComment } />}
    ...
};

const CreateComment = (props) => {
  const { post, onSubmit } = props;
  const [comment, setComment] = useState(commentStr);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onSubmit(post.id, comment);
  };

  return (...);
};
```

### Note

As an aside, setting state in a promise without checking for the component mount state will give you warnings in the console if the component dismounts while a pending promise is active that would trigger a state updated.

Comment: I'm doing it using the callback method. I believe i understand it but as im not able to update the state, it is giving me a problem. It is overwriting my existing state instead of adding to the old state. im using it like this setPost((prevState)=>({ ...prevState,comments:data}))

Comment: but that is overwriting my state

Comment: Im assuming you are passing the response back into the callback and `setPost`. By state being overwritten, do you mean just the comments? If its just the comments, you might try `setPost((prev) => ({ ...prev, comments: [...prev.comments, data] });`

Answer (score 2):

You might have a stale closure. https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/

Try this:

```
setPost(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            id: postS._id,
            username: postS.username,
            title: postS.title,
            body: postS.body,
            comments: postS.comments
        }))
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried this and unfortunately, it didn't work..